# Determine if a user likes a facebook page

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am curious to know how Social Exchange websites check whether a user likes a particular page.

I used http://like4like.org, they don't ask for any Facebook permission (all they know about me is my email)

So the process is

- I like some random page
- They check if I really liked that page (How?)
- I get Points if I liked that page
- I don't get any points if I don't like that page

My research:
 I tried facebook4j to run this fql query with my appId and secret, though anyone can run 
 this in browser
 You can only check for number of likes with this fql query (for pepsi fanpage)

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+like_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url=%27https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpepsi%27

This Returns

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "like_count": 33389390
      }
   ]
}
```

Anyone? who know how do they do it?

---

I already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131579/determine-if-a-user-likes-a-particular-page) before. It was marked duplicate. So I have added some more explanation below.

I just tested a scenario on like4like.org - 
Say my email is a@example.com (created account on like4like.org and facebook with this email)

- I am logged in on like4like.org with email a@example.com On Chrome
- I am also logged in on facebook with email a@example.com On Firefox
- I clicked on a Facebook page link on like4like.org
- As I am not logged in on facebook on Chrome, I can't like the page opened by like4like.org
- but as I am logged in on facebook on Firefox, I copied the page link and opened that Facebook page on Firefox and clicked on like button.
- I closed the opened window (Facebook page opened by like4like.org) on Chrome and I earned nine points

As you can see, like4like.org didn't have any info about my current session on Facebook as I am using it on different browser. Then how the HELL they know I liked the page opened by them ?

> PLEASE NOTE : If I login on Facebook with a different email say
>   b@example.com and likes that Facebook page, I don't get any points.

If what like4like.org is doing is not possible technically then I would ask,
is there any partnership between like4like.org and Facebook?

If it's possible then I would like to see some piece of code.